# Unexpected output of plot

Tags: matlab

I am wanting to do a very simple plot of a polynomial using the `plot(x,y)` function. Here is my full code

```
a = linspace(-3, 0.1, 3);
plot(a, a.^3 - 3*a - 2);
ax = gca;
c = ax.Color;
grid on;
```

Which outputs the following picture

[image: plot here]

Why doesn't the graph extend from -3 to 3 on the x-axis? Why does it stop just after $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) states, in `linspace(x1,x2,n)` `x1` is the begin value, `x2` is the end value and `n` is the number of points. That's exacly what you see on your plot: 3 points: -3, 0.1 and one halfway (because of the linear spacing).

Since you want to have a particular spacing between your points, and not a certain number of points, I suggest you build your vector as:

```
a = -3:.1:3;
```

Comment: Ah, I see. My mistake then. Thank you for the information.